# I have inner tables i need to change <td> css value overflow:visible?

Tags: html

Please help me
 if i found div class="visible" one then change all parent  css style overflow : visible.
  i need to change the 'td'     ccs value oveerflow- hidden to overflow- visible .by using any way to solve this question please.

Like this:

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <td >
                        asdf
                        <table >
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    sdf
                                    <table>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Jill
                                                <div class="visible1">Venkat overflow: visible;</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                sdf
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

           div visible1  > td
     {
         overflow: visible;
         color: red;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong check your css. It must be like this.

```
div.visible1{
overflow:visible;
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div.visible1 {
 overflow: visible;
}
```

In css , a class selector is of the form .classname

Also, you must at least put the CSS inside some  tags , if not in their own file altogether.

Comment: ok..i check div.visible1 this change also apply for <td> also

Comment: you could just set the "visible1" class to the td directly and do td.visible1, or just .visible1.

Comment: how to find visible1 class in div...child <div> class to use parent <td>

Comment: td div.visible1, if i understand your query correctly